# MongoDB: find documents with a given array of subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to find documents which contain given subdocuments, let's say I have the following documents in my `commits` collection:

```
// Document 1
{ 
  "commit": 1,
  "authors" : [
    {"name" : "Joe", "lastname" : "Doe"},
    {"name" : "Joe", "lastname" : "Doe"}
  ] 
}

// Document 2
{ 
  "commit": 2,
  "authors" : [
    {"name" : "Joe", "lastname" : "Doe"},
    {"name" : "John", "lastname" : "Smith"}
  ] 
}

// Document 3
{ 
  "commit": 3,
  "authors" : [
    {"name" : "Joe", "lastname" : "Doe"}
  ] 
}
```

All I want from the above collection is 1st document, since I know I'm looking for a `commit` with 2 `authors` were both have same `name` and `lastname`. So I came up with the query:
`db.commits.find({
      $and: [{'authors': {$elemMatch: {'name': 'Joe,
                                       'lastname': 'Doe'}},
             {'authors': {$elemMatch: {'name': 'Joe,
                                       'lastname': 'Doe'}}],
      'authors': { $size: 2 }
})`

`$size` is used to filter out 3rd document, but the query still returns 2nd document since both `$elemMatch` return True.

I can't use index on subdocuments, since the order of authors used for search is random. Is there a way to remove 2nd document from results without using Mongo's aggregate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for here is a little different from a standard query. In fact you are asking for where the "name" and "lastname" is found in that combination in your array **two** times or more to identify that document.

Standard query arguments do not match "how many times" an array element is matched within a result. But of course you can ask the server to "count" that for you using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match possible documents to reduce the pipeline
    { "$match": {
        "authors": { "$elemMatch": { "name": "Joe", "lastname": "Doe" } }
    }},

    // Unwind the array elements for processing
    { "$unwind": "$authors" },

    // Group back and "count" the matching elements
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "commit": { "$first": "$commit" },
        "authors": { "$push": "$authors" },
        "count": { "$sum": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$and": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$authors.name", "Joe" ] },
                    { "$eq": [ "$authors.lastname", "Doe" ] }
                ]},
                1,
                0
            ]
        }}
    }},

    // Filter out anything that didn't match at least twice
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gte": 2 } } }
])
```

So essentially you but your conditions to match inside the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator which returns `1` where matched and `0` where not, and this is passed to [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to get a total for the document.

Then filter out any documents that did not match 2 or more times

Comment: Then I'll go with aggregation - thanks for your time!